How do I handle exceptions in blazor server events
I'm trying to understand exception handling in Blazor Server (.net 7)

My _Layout.cshtml has a dev with id blazor-error-ui.  It displays if an unhandled exeption bubbles up in the application.  Is Blazor server hardcoded to look for an element with that id, or is the behaviour wired up somewhere in an application?

If my app raises an exception in an OnInitializedAsync, OnInitialized, OnAfterRender or OnAfterRender event, the exception will bubble up and the application will handle it.  I'll see the error in the blazor-error-ui div.  Expected behaviour.

If I have a function which is bound to a property of a component, for example @bind-Value:after, and an exception is thrown in that function, the exception does not bubble up and display in the blazor-error-ui div.

Further, if I have a component that has an event invoked by InvokeAsync, the exception does not bubble up and display in the blazor-error-ui div. The comppnent invoking the function is the Blazorise Tabs controls SelectedTabChanged event, which I beleive doesn't use an await on the InvokeAsync. The Clicked event of the Tab component uses an await, and those exceptions do display in the blazor-error-ui div.  When should InvokeAsync be called with await vs not?  Is that a bug in the component?
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
throw new Exception("This exception will be seen.");
}

    ...

//This function is called by the Tabs component, using InvokeAsync
private void SelectedTabChanged()
{
throw new Exception("This exception will not be seen.");
}
<Tabs @bind-SelectedTab="SelectedTab"
@bind-SelectedTab:after="AfterSelectedTabChanged">
...

private async Task AfterSelectedTabChanged(string tab)
{
throw new Exception("This exception will not be seen.");
}



First, I'm no expert, but as no one else has provided you an answer I'll tell you what I know/believe based on my component knowledge.
Without a full view of your code it's impossible to be specific, but here's some general information on how exceptions are handled in the Blazor UI.
Exceptions in true async methods are captured by the state machine and passed back to the caller through the Task.  The completed Task will have IsFaulted set to true with the exception/s in the Exception property.  Propagation stops here: you need to detect and deal with these exceptions. See https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html#exceptions
If exceptions occur in synchronous code within a component structure they will propagate up to the top component and the blazor-error-ui div.
The console will log an error like this:
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost[111]
      Unhandled exception in circuit 'GDCiHb047ZinuxDrv_woSj7IMglb4jiLdjI_E8A33w0'.
      System.Exception: Hello
         at SO78295291.Components.Pages.Home.OnClick() in C:\Users\shaun\source\repos\SO78295291\SO78295291\Components\Pages\Home.razor:line 41
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem callback, Object arg)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.DispatchEventAsync(UInt64 eventHandlerId, EventFieldInfo fieldInfo, EventArgs eventArgs, Boolean waitForQuiescence)```


The important bit here is that this was a UI event handled by the ComponentBase.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync and it surfaced the error.
Exceptions raised through async calls make through ComponentBase.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync are surfaced byComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion [called by HandleEventAsync] which detects the faulted state of the Task.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost[111]
      Unhandled exception in circuit 'fgeoWKm3DMhdCZrrfEAJMvghwQAeQRbAJdFa6QixUJI'.
      System.Exception: Hello
         at SO78295291.Components.Pages.Home.OnClick()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)

